# Problema con la importación de un componente (Next.js 13 + tailwindcss)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind

Tengo un problema con la importación de un componente en mi proyecto. El archivo headlessui.esm.js ubicado en ./node_modules@headlessui\react\dist/ está generando un error de ReactServerComponentsError.

El error indica que estoy importando un componente que solo funciona en un componente del lado del cliente (Client Component), pero ninguno de sus componentes padres está marcado con la etiqueta "use client". Esto significa que los componentes se están tratando como componentes del lado del servidor (Server Components) de forma predeterminada.

Error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se aprecia ningun error dentro del codigo del componente ni en el page.tsx

[image: Component Navbar]

[image: Archivo pgae.tsx]

Agradecería mucho si alguien pudiera ayudarme con este problema.

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad ¿Que versión de next js?, se [sugiere reemplazar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) lo mas que se pueda de imágenes  por bloques de código